# What's the distance from the midpoint of $AE$ to $BD$ in the pentagon below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In a convex pentagon $ABCDE$: $AB=BC$ and $CD=DE$ ($CD > BC$); If: $BD=K$ and angle $B$ is equal to the measure of angle $D$ which measures $90°$. Calculate the distance from the midpoint of $AE$ to $BD$.
(Answer:$\frac{k}{2}$)

My  progress..

Here is my figure and my considerations:
[image]

Fill in the angles implies $\angle BAC = \angle BCA = \angle DEC=\angle DCE=45^o$

ABDE is a isosceles trapezoid

$\angle ACE =45^o$ but I couldn't demonstrate

therefore $\angle CAE = \angle AEC = 67,5^o$

Law of Cosines$\triangle BCD: k^2=2l^2-2l^2.cos135\implies k^2 = l^2(2+\sqrt2)\therefore k = l\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\\
AC = l\sqrt2$

(by property) $HJ^2 = k.AE\implies HJ=\sqrt{k.AE}$

...???

CORRECTED DRAWING

[image]

Van Aubel's theorem $\angle DJB = 90^0, DJ=JB\\
\triangle DJB: JL^2 = DH.BH = \frac{k}{2}.\frac{k}{2} \therefore JL = \sqrt\frac{k^2}{4}=\frac{k}{2}$

Comment: Question says $CD\gt BC$, but you have drawn $CD=BC$.

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/903638/947379 (duplicate)

Comment: The answer to the other question shows more than is asked: $BJD$ is a right angle AND $BJ=DJ$.

Comment: Hello, any questions or comments on my answer?

Comment: @MathLover it´s perfect..

Comment: Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Draw $CG \perp AC$ and $CF \perp CE$. By midpoint theorem,
$JB \parallel EG$ and $JB = \frac 12 EG$
$JD \parallel AF$ and $JD = \frac 12 AF$

We also see that $\triangle GCE~$ is $~\triangle ACF$ rotated $90^\circ$ clockwise about point $C$. So, $GE \perp AF$ and $GE = AF$.

That shows $JD \perp JB$ and $JD = JB$

So, $JL = BL = \dfrac k2$

Comment: thanks for help